# How can i get alarmed if the master's GTID differs from the slave?

Tags: database, mariadb, master-slave, maxscale

The MaxScale distributes the requests to the MariaDB database -> master/slave server on which the database is located.
What i need is a script running as a cron or something similar which verifies the GTID from master and slaves. If the slaves GTID differs from the masters GTID i want to be informed/alarmed via email.
Unfortunately i have no idea if this is possible somehow and how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can enable [`gtid_strict_mode`](http://mariadb.com/kb/en/gtid/#gtid_strict_mode) to automatically stop the replication if GTIDs from the same domain conflict with what is already in the binlogs. If you are using MaxScale, it will automatically detect this and stop using it.

Note that this will not prevent transactions from other GTID domains from causing problems with your data. This just means you'll have to pay some attention if you're using multi-domain replication.

If you want to be notified of this, you can use the [`script`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-25-common-monitor-parameters/#script) option in MaxScale to trigger a custom script to be launched whenever the server stops replicating.